# Why does Fritz prefer underpromotion in this position?

Tags: engines, evaluation, pawn-promotion, fritz

Why does Fritz prefer underpromotion in this position? How can underpromotion to bishop evaluate so much higher than normal queen promotion?

Can this be a bug in the Fritz 14 chess engine?

[image: Strange evaluation]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's because `1. exf8=Q+ Kxh7 2. Rxd7??` would be stalemate. I think it is a even a theoretical draw after `1. exf8=Q+ Kxh7 2. Qg7+`. Therefore `1. exf8=B+!` (with check!) is better, since white then can keep an extra piece and win easily.

```
[FEN "5r2/3qPbkB/8/7P/8/8/8/1K1R4 w - - 0 1"]

1. exf8=Q+ (1. exf8=B+!) Kxh7 2. Rxd7? (2. Qg7+)
```

Comment: Indeed, after 1.exf8Q+ Kxh7 2.Qg7+, it's a draw, according to the tablebases. It's the famous endgame R+p vs. B where white would be winning with a pawn on h2, h3 or h4, but not on h5!

Comment: @Maxwell86 This endgame has also been discussed in an earlier question http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/2801

Comment: I don't want to seem dumb but what's wrong with kx(whatever is on f8)? I don't see how it varies either, because a queen can do all the bishop can!

Comment: After 1.exf8=Q+ Kxf8 2.Rxd7 black is simply lost, that's what's wrong with it.